# Delay between electric current and light intensity of LED

Tags: led

I'm currently writing a physics report of an experiment, which is about optical fiber.

One of experiments was about compare input & output signal of optical fiber, and the result was this:

[image]

As you can see, there's difference (6ms) between input and output signal, and one question on the experiment instruction was to explain this delay.

I found that two things can affect this delay - optical fiber itself and delay happened at light source: LED. However, I can't sure about both things..

Is the delay between electric current and light intensity of LED significant?

Comment: What about the delay in the detector?

Comment: @MikeJ-UK oops.. I should consider that..

Comment: How long is your fiber?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How long is your fiber, what is the switching time of your emitter and where are you measuring?

You would get a 6ms delay on a 1800km long fiber due to the speed of light.

Another source of delay is afterburn in the LED phosphor. If you are using LEDs designed for fiberoptic transmission they would typically have switching speeds down in the low ns range. There are slower/low cost ones with switching times up to 1us. I work with visible light LED for photography and they exhibit an afterburn in the hundreds of ns. It seems like delay in the LED itself is unlikely.

The speed of your photodetector could of course be a factor. The one I use has a 1 ns rise time and it is hard to imagine the detector itself causing a 6ms delay.

Where are you measuring? I would look at the circuitry that is driving the LED.

Comment: I don't know exactly (because I'm using some kind of experiment kit) but it seems that your guess is right.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: 6ms ~ 1200km. Speed of light in a fiber is only about 200 000 km/s

Comment: +1 photodetector latency.  Most photodetectors need a transimpedance amplifier to turn the small photocurrent into a low-impedance output voltage.  The design tradeoff is speed for sensitivity.  Though 6 ms seems a bit steep even for that.

Comment: @stevenh Oops, yes, refraction. Used to think about that in terms of angles, but you are right. The speed of light varies in different materials. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs switch very fast, typically faster than a microsecond. If they are special-purpose LEDs for communication they should even be much faster than that.

As always you should take a look into the data sheet for the LEDs.

So compared to 6ms this is insignificant.